# Can anyone recommend a .Net open source alternative to Windows Workflow?

Tags: .net, open-source, workflow-foundation

What alternatives are there to Windows Workflow in the .Net stack?  And if you have used these solutions, what made you select them over Windows Workflow and was it a good choice.

---

Update:

I went ahead and selected [stateless](http://blogs.msdn.com/nblumhardt/archive/2009/04/16/state-machines-in-domain-models.aspx) created by Nicholas Blumhardt.  This is a very simple approach to modeling states in a domain.  Below is sample code provided at google:

```
var phoneCall = new StateMachine<State, Trigger>(State.OffHook);

phoneCall.Configure(State.OffHook)
    .Allow(Trigger.CallDialed, State.Ringing);

phoneCall.Configure(State.Ringing)
    .Allow(Trigger.HungUp, State.OffHook)
    .Allow(Trigger.CallConnected, State.Connected);

phoneCall.Configure(State.Connected)
    .OnEntry(t => StartCallTimer())
    .OnExit(t => StopCallTimer())
    .Allow(Trigger.LeftMessage, State.OffHook)
    .Allow(Trigger.HungUp, State.OffHook)
    .Allow(Trigger.PlacedOnHold, State.OnHold);

phoneCall.Configure(State.OnHold)
    .SubstateOf(State.Connected)
    .Allow(Trigger.TakenOffHold, State.Connected)
    .Allow(Trigger.HungUp, State.OffHook)
    .Allow(Trigger.PhoneHurledAgainstWall, State.PhoneDestroyed);
```

As you can see, the state machine uses generics to model the states and their respective triggers.  In other words, you can use enums, integers, string, etc to fit your needs.  Each state of the state machine can be configured with conditional triggers that will fire based on specific criteria.

Comment: Why?

What's wrong with Windows Workflow Foundation?

Comment: -1 for not giving any criteria beyond !WF.

Comment: Actually, I'm inclined to agree that WF has some failings, especially for state machines. I'd be interested to see your own reasons for "!WF", and any replies... At the moment I'm using an expensive product for this... and considering rolling my own workflow engine that works better for my needs (for long running stateful business processes, where the process itself mutates during the lifetime of individual cases).

Comment: I had left this open ended in hope that the answers would drive the discussion as opposed to me narrowing the topics to a single facet of WF.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Windows Workflow Foundation feels like an **overkill** to me **in some situations**. Then, it is easier and simpler to implement your own workflow engine.

Sample references:

- [Simple State Machine project on CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/SimpleStateMachine)
- [Stateless on Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/stateless/)